# Where clause with OR operator Model_Crud, FuelPHP

Tags: mysql, model, where-clause, crud, fuelphp

I'm using win7, FuelPHP 1.6 with xampp 1.8.1 (PHP 5.4.7)

I create new model crud class:

```
class Model_Message extends \Model_Crud {
protected static $_table_name = 'message';

public static function list_message(){
    $list_messages = Model_Message::find(array(
        'select' => array('id', 'type', 'content', 'from_user', 'to_user', 'created_at', 'updated_at'),
        'where' => array(
            'from_user' => '1',
            'or' => array('to_user' => '2'),
        ),
        'limit' => 50,
    ));
    return $list_messages;
}
```

This is the bug

Notice!

```
Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined offset: 0
COREPATH/classes/database/query/builder/where.php @ line 60

55        {
56            foreach ($column as $key => $val)
57            {
58                if (is_array($val))
59                {
60                    $this->and_where($val[0], $val[1], $val[2]);
61                }
62                else
63                {
64                    $this->and_where($key, '=', $val);
65                }
```

If i remove < 'or' => array('to_user' => '2'), >, it work.
But i want filter 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this page : http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/crud.html

You can't use or_where if you use `find()` function.

Here is the good way to do this:

```
public static function list_message(){
    $list_messages = Model_Message::query()->select('id', 'type', 'content', 'from_user', 'to_user', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->where('from_user', '1')->or_where('to_user', '2')->limit(50);
    return $list_messages;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual page [here](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/crud.html#/find_all)

```
class Model_Message extends \Model_Crud {
protected static $_table_name = 'message';

public static function list_message(){
    $list_messages = Model_Message::find(array(
        'select' => array('id', 'type', 'content', 'from_user', 'to_user', 'created_at', 'updated_at'),
        'where' => array(
            array('from_user' => '1'), // <-- note the array
            'or' => array('to_user' => '2'),
        ),
        'limit' => 50,
    ));
    return $list_messages;
}
```

It just looks like your syntax is slightly wrong

Comment: $entry = Model_Article::find('all', array(
        'where' => array(
            array('category_id', 1),
            'or' => array(
                array('category_id', 2),
            ),
        ),
    ));    =======> Not work

Comment: by this page https://github.com/fuel/fuel/blob/1.6/master/CHANGELOG.md#v16 the method Find() is deprecated.

Comment: This is about Model_Crud, not about ORM.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by this way..

```
public static function list_message(){
    $list_messages = Model_Message::query()->select('id', 'type', 'content', 'from_user', 'to_user', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->where('from_user', 1)->or_where('to_user', 2)->limit(50);
    return $list_messages;
}
```

If you need more reference, take a look at this part of docs.
http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/crud.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not about ORM as WanWizard says.

Model_Crud can not use "or" by an usual way because the "find" static method calls "Model_DB::and_where() inside. I found a way this:

```
$list_messages = Model_Message::find(array(
    'select' => array('id', 'type', 'content', /*...*/ 'created_at', 'updated_at'),
    'where' => function($query) {
       $query->where("from_user", 1)->or_where("to_user", 2);
    },
    'limit' => 50,
));
```

not smart...isn't there any good solution?

http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/database/qb_where.html#/method_and_where